# How can I achieve the vocal affect found on "The Jokers" voice in the film "The Dark Knight" 2008

Tags: sound-effects, film-sound-design, voice-manipulation

I'm experimenting on modifying vocals to make them sound dark and creepy.

What process is used to make Christian Bale (Batman) and Heath Ledger (The Joker) voice so dark/distorted/creepy.

Here's a clip of the Joker in the hostage scene. He shouts "Look at me" @ 1.04:

Also, here's the famous "Why so serious" clip (@ 0.42):

Side note: If you can name any decent VST plugins that specialise in manipulating vocals/speech, please leave references in the comment box. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: your links are missing, but i guess everybody knows these scenes by heart.

Comment: Strange, I've just checked and there's two embedded players and both clips work fine??!

Comment: perhaps i have some blocker that's keeping it from showing up. anyone else see the links?

Comment: I saw the links okay so must be you Arnoud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll find a magic plug-in for this.  The majority of the effect is performance from the actor and then some EQ, reverb and maybe a bit of distortion.  Remember that an FX plug-in will enhance what is already there, but if it's not there is the first place (from the actors) no amount of processing will give you the magic you desire.

Comment: I'll experiment more with your comments in mind. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to get some good results if you have the opportunity to work directly with the actors.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

totally agree with Bit Depth. I do alot of work with actors and that kind of effect you're hearing is all in the performance. Maybe some slight distortion or harmonic enhancers to bring out the frequencies but I don't think that's a plug in effect.